# Objective c error with extern

Tags: objective-c

I have a class named MyClass. And in the file MyClass.m I start the coding with this line:
`extern MyClass *gMyClass;`

and I got this error:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
```

What's the problem? What do you think?

Comment: You will need to post more code & more info like where is that line placed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `MyClass` is declared before the `extern` statement. Are you importing `MyClass.h` before you declare `extern MyClass *gMyClass`?

Also, it seems a bit odd that the `gMyClass` global is declared `extern` in the class's `.m` file. Usually, the `extern MyClass *gMyClass` statement is either put in the header, or you make the `*gMyClass` static and allow access to it through class methods in your `MyClass` class.